# Scroll inside div instead of scrolling page

Tags: html, css, scroll

I am trying to scroll using the mouse inside a div, but it is scrolling the entire page.

I need to scroll inside the Facebook widget, and also inside the Press Release div.

How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: just do a `overflow-y:scroll` in your css for that particular div

Comment: Make sure the browser knows which element you want to scroll, e.g. by clicking in it first to give it focus. If that doesn't help, a demo of the problem would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

`#div
{ overflow: scroll; }`
If for example your div tag name is div.. you can use the code above in your CSS file
It worked well for me.

Comment: The OP already has scroll bars visible in the picture, so that's not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use this one. overflow: auto will solve this.

```css
.scroll {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  background: #565656;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
  <h1>Scroll Heading</h1>  
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <p>Last Content</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.Content
{
 height:224px;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @SergeyDenisov i do believe it does? the author asks how to solve his problem and i comes up with a (working) solution i may not have included a solution description but a solution it is.